# Fedora бесконечные сбои системы после замены проц+мать

Tags: linux, kernel, fedora, core

Не так давно обновил железо (мать, проц, и память). После исследования ситуации выяснил, что систему переустанавливать не нужно. После некоторых манипуляций все же пришлось переустановить загрузчик на УЕФИ, но все завелось. Но посыпались проблемы в виде подвисания системы на несколько секунд, за чем следовала перезагрузка. После чего зачастую видел такую картину [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема (сбой) в ядре kernel-core, отчёт невозможен, так как пишет, что проблема в оборудовании.
Параллельно установленная Windows — таких проблем пока не наблюдал. Винда была переустановлена, в отличии от Федоры.

Comment: в таких случаях в линуксе показывают вывод dmesg хотя бы. А картинки от КО мало чем помогут.

Comment: Какой проц, амд?

Comment: @eri, проц — AMD

Comment: @KoVadim, можно и сейчас, или желательно после сбоя?

Comment: логично, что сразу после сбоя. там будет видно, что пошло не так (скорее всего)

Answer (score 1):

Пункт ноль - обнови биос.

Во первых фирмварь. Тут или на свободных дровах или на фирмовых... Для свободных я беру из этого пака https://github.com/q3aql/drivers-linux-firmware

Фирменные на сайте АМД. Для них ещё подойдут не все ядра, последние версии иксов не запускаются.

Во вторых после установки фирмвари 50% шанс, что вообще перестанет запускаться. Надо затюнить драйвер на некоторых процах, R5 там... https://askubuntu.com/a/1198286/179720 прокатит для 4ого ядра параметр в грабе.

Comment: по моему, этот ответ "ни о чем".

Comment: 0) БИОС обновил, 1) у меня Федора, а ссылка на Убунту

Comment: @YuchimenkoIgor дмесг приложите к вопросу?

Comment: linux-firmware пакет стоит? может там уже есть

Comment: @KoVadim как и вопрос) пытаюсь ванговать

Comment: @eri, dnf info говорит, что linux-firmware установлен

Comment: @eri, https://paste.centos.org/view/5f8533c4

Comment: 600ая нвидия) безумная серия. тоже крови много попила. где-то был комп с таким чипом на работе, гляну что я там делал